# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu server 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-12.04

I'm confronted with problem that I'm not able to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04LTS with the following command:

`$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

Then upgrade with command:

`$ sudo do-release-upgrade`

or

`$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

The last command leads to the following result:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

The kernel is:

`$ uname -r 
3.2.0-126-generic`

The end of file `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts` is:

`Dist: trusty
Name: Trusty Tahr
Version: 14.04.1 LTS
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 14:04:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 14.04.1 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/trusty.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/trusty.tar.gz.gpg`


The content of `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is: 


`[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts`

I tried to change Prompt from lts to normal and run the upgrade command but got the same result.

The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` is: 


`deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse`

I will be really grateful for anyone who can give me a hand to solve the problem. It has confused me for such a long time.

Comment: please ask general questions about Ubuntu at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04, released in 2012, is nowadays a very old operating system. It has reached the ["End Of Life Date"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) in August 2017, and this is probably the reason why the upgrade fails.

You may want to verify this by typing `ubuntu-support-status` in the console.

To upgrade the system, I would suggest to make a backup of your data and to do a fresh install of a more recent version of ubuntu (the current release is 18.04.1 LTS).

Comment: Thanks! I seems that I have to reinstall a newer version of os.